# intersection of cone axis with plane

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

So when the plane intersect the cone, the intersection is a conic. Is (or when is) the axis (of the cone) intersection with the plane the focus of the conic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just when the plane is orthogonal to the axis, since the focus lies on the [Dandelin sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dandelin_spheres) that is tangent to the plane and the cone.